# Unix - Executing same command on same file in multiple sub directories

Tags: bash, unix, loops, execute

I have 36 subdirectories in the same directory named `10,11,12,....45`

In each subdirectory there is a file named `pressure.sh` that I would like to execute a command on, the command is `qsub`

I was wondering if there was a way where I could execute the command qsub on each `pressure.sh` file in each subdirectory 10-45 from the parent directory?

So I am looking for a code that executes "`qsub pressure.sh`" one by one in each subdirectory so I do not have to do it one by one every time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a glob:

```
for i in */pressure.sh; do
    qsub $i
done
```

To be more explicit about the directories, you can use a range:

```
for i in {10..45}/pressure.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is with `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name pressure.sh | xargs -n 1 qsub
```

which finds all `pressure.sh`, even if deeper than one level.